# Save and restore total app state after exit (app has 1 activity and 1 RecyclerView)

Tags: android, savestate, android-savedstate

After poking through threads on the subject I still cannot figure out what to do. The thing is, I have a quite simple app, which has just one activity and one recycler view, where user can add some text. Now after I switch to another app or after I restart the app everything is lost. I know that I can preserve some necessary variables via `onSaveInstanceState()` method and Bundle, but is there a way to save absolutely everything? States of all view and all the data of the RecyclerView? Without writing down explicitly every singe variable?
Thank you!!

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use shared preferences to preserve all types of variable and objects but you have to save all your variables after your activity is destroyed and read them when your activity is created

Comment: Bilal thank you for the answer, could you perhaps give a snippet of the code that saves the whole state of the app? Or share a link where I may see it?